# Why does my WebGet return an empty class

Tags: c#, json, xml, wcf, rest

When I try to retrieve a class filled with data I never retrieve the right data. The booleans in the class below always return false.

When I call the same `GetState` function from Postman of from Chrome without making any changes I do get the results I would expect

I have a class like wich looks something like this:

```
        [DataContract]
        public class State
        {
            [DataMember]
            public bool Camera_1_Ok { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool Camera_2_Ok { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public bool Camera_3_Ok { get; set; }
        }
```

My ServiceContract Interface looks like this:

```
        [ServiceContract]
        interface IConnectionService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetState", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
            State GetState();
        }
```

The GetState implementation looks like this:

```
        [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
        public sealed class WCFServer : IConnectionService
        {
            public State GetState()
            {
                State tempState = new State();
                State.Camera_1_OK = true;
                State.Camera_2_OK = true;
                State.Camera_3_OK = true;

                return tempState;
            }
```

I made sure that both sides of the service have the same "State" class and the same "IConnectionService" Interface.

How come the booleans in the class that is returned to the calling machine are never set? And how come I do get the right data when I call the function from Chrome or Postman?

Awnsers to similar questions mentioned the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes but I already added these to my class.

PS: When I set the `ResponseFormat` to `WebMessageFormat.Json` on both sides of the service I get the data as expected. Sadly this will not be the solution since `Xml` format was requested.

Comment: Inspect the request using Fiddler and find out how they are different when a request is made in both scenarios. Also try to not set the responseformat and let the framework handle it. It decides the responseformat from the "Accept" response header and returns in the format appropriately.

Comment: I could not find any differences with fiddler except from the Content-Type wich holds if it's in Json or XML format. so no luck there.

Comment: Can you post on how your config looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

Then return a System.IO.Stream from your function.

After that, try to de-serialize your stream at receiver.